# createTrackbar() holds constant input for video input in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Writing program for reading video frames in opencv using cpp and wanted to control bin input via createTrackbar(). Following is code written:

```
int bins = 25;
// Create Trackbar to enter the number of bins
char* window_image = "Source image";
namedWindow(window_image, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

createTrackbar("* Hue  bins: ", window_image, &bins, 180, Hist_and_Backproj);
```

The above code works good for images. Able to change bin value with trackbar displayed on output window "Source image". On moving the trackbar with cursor moves with it to desired value. On releasing cursor to new value it will take that new value as input.

When implemented for video, the trackbar displayed on output window "Source video", on moving the trackbar with cursor moves with it to desired value. On relasing cursor it instantly goes to initial value (25) instead of taking new value.

Please let me know where to improve the code. 
Thank you for your support in advance.

Comment: Hi, there! Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help people identify the issues faster.

Comment: We need a full code. Standart example from OpenCV with trackbar works correctly:  ./example_dnn_object_detection -c=deploy.prototxt -m=res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel -i=Megamind.avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer after much time lost - minor code mistake.
The variable 'bins' was getting called from loop which was meant for video. Corrected. 
Thanks though.